# HQL query: filtering LocalDateTime property by LocalTime

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hql, localtime

I have a problem to create a query which gives back all value where time is between two parameter.

How can I get back those works where endTime time part is between the given LocalTime-s?

```
public class Work {

  private Long id;
  private LocalDateTime endTime;

  //getters setters 
} 

@Query("SELECT new package.dto(w.id) FROM Work w WHERE TIME(w.endTime) BETWEEN :from AND :to)
List<Dto> createDtoList(LocalTime from, LocalTime to);
```

Comment: By the way, usually best to *not* use SQL `BETWEEN` for date-time ranges. Search Stack Overflow to learn about Half-Open approach.

Comment: You have a query there. So what are you trying to ask? What exactly is the “problem” you spoke of?

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your column? What database engine?

Comment: It is a postresql timestamp. But here I want to use hql. I just wanted to filter those localDateTime variables which time part is between two localTime variables.
Btw I found the solution `CAST(endTime AS java.lang.Time)`

Comment: You mean `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`? You need to be quite clear on which of the two kinds of timestamp is your column. Also, this detail should be posted as an edit to your Question rather than as a Comment.

Comment: If you have a solution, here on Stack Overflow you are encouraged to post and accept your own Answer to your own Question.

Comment: I think it is irrelevant, how it is stored in db, because I use hql which should map (read and write) on db, by property type. The property time here is LocalDateTime; and I just wanted to read the Time part of that property in query. 

Also I just wanted to know how to cast LocalDateTime to Time in hql query

Comment: @Basil Bourque in the database, the property type is a simple timestamp. (PostreSQL)

Answer (score 0):

CAST(endTime AS java.lang.Time)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).